# Parametrizations of $ x^4+y^4+z^4=9t^2 $ integer solutions

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, pythagorean-triples

I would like to derive all the parametrizations for the nontrivial solutions of this Diophantine equation:

$ x^4+y^4+z^4=9t^2 $

I already know that with the Fauquembergue's parametrization I can find infinite solutions (essentially multiplying by 3 the terms in the parametrization, or in the Pythagorean triple), like this one:

$ 60^4 + 45^4 + 36^4 = 9(1443)^2 $

$ 108^4+135^4+180^4 = 9(12987)^2 $

But I even know that there are more solutions (I found the last two from $ x^4+y^4+z^4=t^4 $):

$(155, 260, 296, 37747)$

$(95800, 217519, 414560, 59496731787)$

$ (2682440, 15365639, 18796760, 141668657747643) $

and they don't seem to come out from the result I found on [here](http://www.maroon.dti.ne.jp/fermat/dioph69e.html) (none of the fourth powers is divisible by 3).

So which kind of parametrization will give those solutions?

Comment: Maybe it helps (or not) to understand [pythagorean quadruples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_quadruple) first, since you have $\left(x^2\right)^2+\left(y^2\right)^2+\left(z^2\right)^2=\left(3t\right)^2$.

Comment: I guess that with the Pythagorean quadruples parametrizations I can find again the solutions already found with Fauquembergue's one. I tried to solve the system of 4 equations with one of the other solutions but cam out with nothing. Thank you anyway!

Comment: A pythagorean quadruple works as a solution provided $a,b,c$ are squares and $d$ is a multiple of $3$. In the parametrization for pyth. quadruples, $a,b,c$ are quadratic in their parameters. So you have three homogeneous quadratic relations, and each of _those_ should have its own param. If you could isolate those params. and identify their intersections, then you would probably have this solved. Filtering out those params. where $d$ is not a multiple of $3$ should be easy at that point. Hard to assess this approach until seeing the params. for those three quadratic relations.

Comment: Solutions of $x^4+y^4+z^4=t^4$ are derived from using elliptic curves.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Diophantine equation,

$$x^4+y^4+z^4 = nt^2$$

has quite an interesting history, being studied by Fauquembergue, Proth, Ramanujan, etc.

**I. Case n = 1**

As alluded to by the OP, Fauquembergue found that if $a^2+b^2 = c^2$, then,

$$(ab)^4+(ac)^4+(bc)^4 = (a^4+a^2b^2+b^4)^2$$

So using the simplest Pythagorean triple $(3,4,5)$ and multiplying both sides by $3^4$, we get the first solution of the OP,

$$ 60^4 + 45^4 + 36^4 = 9(1443)^2 $$

**II. Case n = 2**

Even simpler, Proth found that if $a+b+c = 0$, then,

$$a^4+b^4+c^4 = 2(ab+ac+bc)^2$$

extended by Ramanujan to,

$$a^4(b-c)^4 + b^4(a-c)^4 + c^4(a-b)^4 = 2(ab+ac+bc)^4$$

and so on for all $2(ab+ac+bc)^k$ with even $k.$

**III. Case n = 9**

We can use Fauquembergue's identity and multiply both sides by $3^4$ to get $n=9$. But if we wish that both sides have no common factor, we can employ a particular case of the result by [Demjanenko-Elkies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_sum_of_powers_conjecture#Counterexamples),

$$(85v^2 + 484v - 313)^4 + (68v^2 - 586v + 10)^4 + (2u)^4 = 9t^2$$

where $t = 3(119v^2 - 68v + 121)^2$ and,

$$22030 + 28849v - 56158v^2 + 36941v^3 - 31790v^4 = u^2$$

This is an *elliptic curve*, with one initial rational point $v = -31/467$ and an *infinite* more. The first point gives,

$$2682440^4+15365639^4+18796760^4 = 9\times141668657747643^2$$

noticed by the OP.

**IV. Remark**

The small co-prime solution found by the OP,

$$155^4+260^4+296^4 = 9\times37747^2$$

can also be treated as the initial point of an elliptic curve, and it would be nice to know if it satisfies a simpler polynomial identity than the Demjanenko-Elkies.

Comment: Thank you for your great answer!